# Google Assistant SDK (C++) - Broadcast Command

Tags: c++, google-assistant-sdk

I was using the sample application and sending a broadcast command to the Google Assistant using the *--text_input* option and everything was working correctly.

Now, in the latest version, the Google Assistant responds with: "Something went wrong. Something went wrong," but I don't get an error, even with *verbose* turned on. Do I need to do something different than before? Other commands, such as "What time is it?" work correctly. Here is the output from the broadcast request:

```
$ ./run_assistant --text_input "Broadcast Dinner" --credentials_file ./credentials.json
    Using locale en-US
    assistant_sdk robots_pem:
    assistant_sdk CreateCustomChannel(embeddedassistant.googleapis.com:443, creds, arg)

    assistant_sdk wrote first request: config { audio_out_config { encoding: LINEAR16 sample_rate_hertz: 16000 } dialog_state_in { language_code: "en-US" } device_config { device_id: "default" device_model_id: "default" } text_query: "Broadcast Dinner" }
    assistant_sdk waiting for response ...
    assistant_sdk Got a response
$
```

I also posted this on the Google Communities page, I hope it's OK to post the question in both places.

Comment: If you look at your Google Activity, you'll see "I wasn't able to broadcast. Try again later." Looks like something has changed on Google's end which has disabled this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with your code.

I have the same issue on a project of mine that has been working without issue for months, and then around the 14th May it all stopped working.

We need Google to resolve this one.

Comment: Google confirmed it's a bug that they're tracking down.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue .. was working a week or so ago, then I went on hols and it isn't anymore.
If you use the voice input and ask it to broadcast it says "sorry I can't find any other speakers connected to your home network, so I can't broadcast your message"